# Java convert sequence of strings into logical function

Tags: java

I have several strings chains written as follows:

**(A and (B or C)**

**(A and D) or (A and (B or C))**

Where A, B, C and D are all booleans. 
The full list of possible combinations is large, I am looking for a flexible code that can translate the full text and evaluate the result. Any thoughts?

Comment: you should look into parsers, or use a library for boolean expression evaluation.

Comment: First thought: "k, so where's the problem that requires help from other SO users? This sounds like something you can google for without any issues?" Remember, SO is not a general help forum, it is a Q&A site with fairly [specific policy](/help/on-topic) on what is appropriate to ask here, and questions on "what to do or what to look for" before you've even started writing any code [basically mean it's too early in your project to post questions here](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your type of question (properly asked) *could* be on-topic on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Take a look into context free grammars. Making a parser for your particular grammar would not be too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static boolean eval(String s, Map<String, Boolean> variables) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    for (Entry<String, Boolean> e : variables.entrySet())
        engine.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    return (boolean) engine.eval(s.replace("and", "&&").replace("or", "||"));
}
```

and

```
boolean result = eval("(A and (B or C))", Map.of("A", true, "B", false, "C", true));
System.out.println(result);
// -> true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @saka1029, it works well. I only had to add Map.Entry to the for loop. Many thanks!